# Event creation on facebook using playframework

Tags: java, playframework

I want to know what is the return function of event creation through the Facebook API ?

If event creation is successful it returns `event id` but how could I show that in code that the event has been created successfully ?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the response status.

```
//Do Facebook api call
Response r = WS.url("graphapi").get().get();

if (r.getStatus() == 200 ) {
  Logger.info("api success");
} else {
  Logger.error("api error");
}
```